# POI loses date format on override

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to override only some characters, only in string cells, but when i write the file it does'nt keep the style, i don't care about font or colors but in the second override the date rows are transformed to number columns.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    FormatReader archivoOriginal = new FormatReader("file.xls");
    Sheet hoja;
    hoja = archivoOriginal.getSheet(0);

    int rowStart = 0;
    int rowEnd = hoja.getLastRowNum();        

    //Read File
    for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum <= rowEnd; rowNum++) {
        Row r = hoja.getRow(rowNum);
        int lstCell = r.getLastCellNum();
        for (int i = 0; i < lstCell; i++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(i);
            if (c == null) {
                continue;
            }
            String campoValor = "";
            //CopyStyle of the cell
            c.setCellStyle(c.getCellStyle());
            switch (c.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    campoValor = c.getStringCellValue();
                    c.setCellValue(Funciones.replaceChars(campoValor));
                break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(c)) {
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date date = c.getDateCellValue();
                        campoValor = df.format(date);
                        c.setCellValue(date);
                    } else {
                        double d = c.getNumericCellValue();
                        campoValor = Double.toString(d);
                        c.setCellValue(d);
                    }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //End reading

    //Override File

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("file.xls");
    archivoOriginal.getArchivo().write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    //Close File reader
    archivoOriginal.close();

}
```

Comment: What is `FormatReader`? And what version of  `apache poi` is used to create `Sheet hoja`,  `Row r` and `Cell c`? Because if I use the current version 3.16 and really a `HSSFWorkbook`, I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing.

Comment: I'm using POI 3.15, import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;, thaks i'll try to update POI but i think it genarates conflicts, i remenber that i tried and i could'nt do it, but i'll give it a secound chance

Comment: My mistake, I added HSSFOptimiser.optimiseCellStyles((HSSFWorkbook)archivo); in the init part thaks